# Handling default form values with jquery.validationEngine.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am using **jquery.validationEngine.js**  for form validation .

I was downloaded this js from http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

this site.But it not works for checking validation for default value such as I have first name field whose value is "First Name".I want validation for checking that this field should not be blank but it not works because it contains default value "First Name".

Also I want this should work in **jquery.validationEngine.js** file because I have to many validations on form & I am using this js.

My field is

```
<input type="text" id="Uname" name="Uname" value="User Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='User Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='User Name';" />
```

If anyone using this file let me know & help to solve this problem.

Comment: code is to large it exceeds chearacter limit for posting code you can check this file from this link http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Comment: Post *your* code, as in the HTML code for the form that you are validating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery.validation - how to ignore default values when validating mandatory fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733922/jquery-validation-how-to-ignore-default-values-when-validating-mandatory-fields)

Comment: Better one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133094/how-do-you-validate-optional-fields-with-default-value

Comment: [Here][1] is the similar question and answers.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733922/jquery-validation-how-to-ignore-default-values-when-validating-mandatory-fields/7063899#7063899

Comment: [Here is the similar question and answers.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733922/jquery-validation-how-to-ignore-default-values-when-validating-mandatory-fields/7063899#7063899

Comment: Here is the similar question and answers.

 <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733922/jquery-validation-how-to-ignore-default-values-when-validating-mandatory-fields/7063899#7063899>

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use validationEngine to validate your form the way you describe, there appear to be at least three solutions based on the documentation.

1) You can create a new custom regex in the translation file for each default text value, and then add that custom regex to the relevant form item.  This is probably the trickiest of your options, as you will need to use a negative lookahead or something similar to get the regex correct.

2) Have the validator call one or more functions that you write to handle your special cases.  I don't know if validationEngine allows you to pass parameters to the function--the documentation says nothing about that--so I'd guess it doesn't.  This may mean that you will need to either write a separate function for each default value or else use a global variable to indicate the default value you are checking for.  A function for your `Uname` field in your code snippet might look like this:

```
function checkUname(field, rules, i, options){
  if (field.val() == "User Name") {
     return "You must type in your username.";
  }
```

Once that function is defined, you can use something like this to use it:

```
<input type="text" class="form validate[required,funcCall[checkUname]]" id="Uname" name="Uname" value="User Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='User Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='User Name';" />
```

3) You can write a single JavaScript function that goes through each field in your form and, if it finds the default value, changes it to an empty string.  Then attach that function to the `onsubmit` event in your form.  This may be the easiest option, but it depends on your function running before the validationEngine code.  If that's not the case, then it won't work.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form" class="form validate[required]" id="Uname" name="Uname" value="User Name" onfocus="if(this.value=='User Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='User Name';" />
                </div>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example
[How do you validate optional fields with default value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133094/how-do-you-validate-optional-fields-with-default-value)

Otherwise see the question I posted as identical question with the possible change

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) {
  if (element.value == element.defaultValue) return false;
}
```

instead of the switch/case

```
<input type="text" id="Uname" name="Uname" value="User Name" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value=''" 
onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.defaultValue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the placeholder value using the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute instead of JavaScript.